# Is J query Session is different from .net Session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, vb.net

Is $.session is diffrent from Session("")?

Am setting session in jquery like
   $.session.set("tempUsername", '<%=hdnUserName.Value%>');

try to get it in Session("tempUsername") in vb.net

It shows empty ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutly different.

http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/01/20/session-handling-using-jquery/

It's the same like cookies that deletes after browser closing.

Answer (score 0):

Both are completely different concepts

[**Dot Net Session**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a
>   user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is
>   a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP
>   request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no
>   knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests.
>   ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during
>   a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist
>   variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET
>   session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.

**JQuery Session**

> Jquery session is just an abstraction on **window.sessionStorage** that
>   browser provide. If you save some value in session storage then it will be available on that particular tab of the browser.

For more information on session storage  please follow this [link on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)